# GRUB is not working

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub

I've installed ubuntu alongside windows7 in laptop. When I restart after installation, it is directly entering Ubuntu OS. It is not showing the option which OS to choose. Windows is not deleted because I can access the files and other things that are in windows OS and 'disk usage analyser' is showing the assigned memory of ubuntu while partitioning. How can I fix this GRUB error.

Answer (score 2):

while your system is turning on, press and hold shift until grub menu loads.

check whether grub lists your windows partition, if it didn't show, try updating grub by using

```
sudo update-grub
```

if still it doesn't work, use boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```